# How to Consume & get Proper Data of WCF return Json in J2ME

Tags: c#, wcf, java-me, utf-8

I have created a WCF Service and then after consuming this service in J2ME.
My WCF Service is:

```
IService:
        [OperationContract]
                [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = "/GetByCity/Limit={limit}", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
    RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
                ItemList GetByCity(string limit);

Service.CS :

public ItemList GetByCity(string limit)
        {           
            DataTable City = ds.Tables["City"];
                var items = WithHTML(City, limit);
                return new ItemList { Items = items };
        }
 public List<Item> WithHTML(DataTable City, string limit)
        {
            var items = (from d in City.AsEnumerable()
                         where d.Field<string>("strMainHin") != string.Empty
                         orderby d.Field<DateTime>("dtPosted")
                         select new Item
                         {
                             ItemId = d.Field<Int32>("intId").ToString(),
                             ItemLine = htmlEscapes(d.Field<string>("strMainHin")),
                             Photo = @"http://192.168.1.17:801/ImageById/" + d.Field<Int32>("intId") + ".jpg"
                         }).Take(Convert.ToInt32(limit)).ToList();

            return items;
        }
 public string htmlEscape(string input)
        {            var output = Regex.Replace(input, @"&#([0-9]*);", x => new String((char)int.Parse(x.Groups[1].Value), 1));
            return output;
        }
```

Now the output of this service in the URL `http://192.168.1.17:803/Patrika/Service.svc/GetByCity/Limit=2`
is:

```
{"Items":[{"ItemLine":"डेढ़ करोड़ का क्रिकेट सट्टा पकड़ा","ItemId":"821745","Photo":"http:\/\/192.168.1.17:801\/ImageById\/821745.jpg"},{"ItemLine":"पार्किग का इंतजाम नहीं, तो जब्त होंगे वाहन","ItemId":"824837","Photo":"http:\/\/192.168.1.17:801\/ImageById\/824837.jpg"}]}
```

But when i Consume this service in J2ME through this link:
'http://192.168.1.17:803/Patrika/Service.svc/GetByCity/Limit=2'
the Unicode or UTF-8 i am giving return responce in J2ME is:

```
{"ItemLine":"à¤¡à¥‡à¤¢à¤¼ à¤•à¤°à¥‹à¤¡à¤¼ à¤•à¤¾ à¤•à¥?à¤°à¤¿à¤•à¥‡à¤Ÿ à¤¸à¤Ÿà¥?à¤Ÿà¤¾ à¤ªà¤•à¤¡à¤¼à¤¾"}
```

Everything is going fine but only this string with some unicode is giving wrong output.
then i tried to send only one data that is:

```
{"ItemLine":"डेढ़ करोड़ का क्रिकेट सट्टा पकड़ा"}
```

then at J2ME end i took this string into a JSON Object and put it into a label like following:

```
Label l1=new Label("ItemLine");
this.component.add(l1);
```

but the output is the same as above that bad json string.

Comment: Your showing two JSON snippets, a good one and bad one with a serious encoding problem. Where and how exactly have they been captured? What's software is involved between these two locations?

Comment: actually when i am done with WCF i tried to consume this Service in J2ME in Eclipse software it showing me the bad snippet.
WCf as u know is done by Visual Studio 2010.
and J2ME is doing on Eclipse

Comment: Please be more exact where and how you have captured these two JSON snippets. If you have debugged the client and the server and copied them out of the debugger, then tell us exactly where in the code you have stopped the applications. And please provide more information about the J2ME application? What classes are you using the retrieve and parse the JSON data?

Comment: I'd really like to help you. But you need to post more information, in particular the relevant code on the J2ME side. And J2ME does support UTF-8. So that can't be the problem.

Comment: Okk then i will edit my question again.. wait

Comment: @Codo :: I have edited my question. this is the only thing i am doing

Comment: actually J2ME code is at the client side so i can get only this much of information
Should i use default JSON Serializer or something but i dont know how to work with that...

Comment: I'm confused. What prevents you from posting the J2ME code that retrieves the JSON data and parses it? What prevents you from telling us where exactly you got the JSON samples from? The relevant information is still missing.

Comment: the main thing is as i wrote in my last commnt that i dont have the code that is on client side i am developing WCF Service at my end...
thing is they told me that they are doing the thing which i have mentioned in my question details...
i don't know code but only the output they are getting in their JSON Object and showing on to the Label..

Comment: If the first JSON snippet in your question was produced without the J2ME code involved and using the same HTTP request the device would use, then the WCF service is working correctly and according to JSON standards. So the problem would be in the J2ME code and those people with access to that code would need to fix it (and possibly ask questions here). Trying to trick WCF into producing incorrect JSON data most likely won't work and is a bad idea anyway.

Comment: Dude thank you so much for being with me as u said above the problem is with their code and i told them finally that this service is alright and send that mail to their head n well now everything working fine...
thank you so much again... :) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IService:

```
  [OperationContract]
                [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = "/GetByCity/Limit={limit}", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
    RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
                ItemList GetByCity(string limit);
```

Service.CS :

```
public ItemList GetByCity(string limit)
        {           
            DataTable City = ds.Tables["City"];
                var items = WithHTML(City, limit);
                return new ItemList { Items = items };
        }
 public List<Item> WithHTML(DataTable City, string limit)
        {
            var items = (from d in City.AsEnumerable()
                         where d.Field<string>("strMainHin") != string.Empty
                         orderby d.Field<DateTime>("dtPosted")
                         select new Item
                         {
                             ItemId = d.Field<Int32>("intId").ToString(),
                             ItemLine = htmlEscapes(d.Field<string>("strMainHin")),
                             Photo = @"http://192.168.1.17:801/ImageById/" + d.Field<Int32>("intId") + ".jpg"
                         }).Take(Convert.ToInt32(limit)).ToList();

            return items;
        }
 public string htmlEscape(string input)
        {            var output = String.Join("", WebUtility.HtmlDecode(input).Select(x => "\\u" + ((int)x).ToString("X4")));
            return output;
        }
```

In the Last method input is:

```
&#2351;&#2369;&#2357;&#2340;&#2368; &#2325;&#2366; &#2309;&#2343;&#2332;&#2354;&#2366; &#2358;&#2357; &#2350;&#2367;&#2354;&#2366;
```

and the Output is:

```
\\\u0921\\\u0947\\\u0922\\\u093C \\\u0915\\\u0930\\\u094B\\\u0921\\\u093C \\\u0915\\\u093E \\\u0915\\\u094D\\\u0930\\\u093F\\\u0915\\\u0947\\\u091F \\\u0938\\\u091F\\\u094D\\\u091F\\\u093E \\\u092A\\\u0915\\\u0921\\\u093C\\\u093E
```

In this output I got extra '\' so this was not rendering in J2ME.

So at the Client end means at J2ME side I split the string which I got and then convert `\\\` to `\\` .

And that's all I got my Hindi Font: *युवती का अधजला शव मिला*.

Thanks to @Codo who helped me a lot.